# AngularJS directive changing ability to modify scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's a plunkr with my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx830ekQyP7YBqmRB4Nd?p=preview

Click "Open", then click on "5". Notice how it changes to "test"? Now, type something into Body. It'll either say "Say a little more..." or "Now for the title". Either way, click the button again, and notice how it doesn't change to "test"? Why not? If I remove the directive, the button changes to "test" with or without text in the body.

I know this has to do with the scope in the directive, but I don't understand what exactly is wrong. Can you explain? Thanks.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ngDialog']).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ngDialog) {
//$scope.submitPostValue = "OK";

$scope.submitPost = function() {
  $scope.submitPostValue = 'test';
};

$scope.open = function () {
console.log('open');
    $scope.submitPostValue = '5';
            ngDialog.openConfirm({
            template: 'postModal',
            showClose: true,
            trapFocus: false,
            scope: $scope,
        }).then(function (success) {
        }, function (error) {

        });
};
 }).directive('bodyValidator', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function customValidator(ngModelValue) {
            if(ngModelValue.length > 0){
                if(ngModelValue.length < 10) {
                    scope.submitPostValue = "Say a little more...";
                    scope.bodyValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    scope.bodyValid = true;
                    if(scope.titleValid)
                        scope.submitPostValue = "Submit";
                    else
                        scope.submitPostValue = "Now for the title..."
                   }
                }
                else {
                scope.submitPostValue = "Enter a body...";
                scope.bodyValid = false;
            } 

            return ngModelValue;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap all your variables into an object.

Define `$scope.obj = {};` first and change all your `scope.submitPostValue` to `$scope.obj.submitPostValue`. In your HTML, change `ng-value='submitPostValue'` to `ng-value=obj.submitPostValue`.

Comment: A directive creates it's own scope under its parent scope. When you update a variable in directive, it updates the value in the directive scope. Wrapping variables into an object can avoid this issue because objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn Song.